# Deployed REST API does not display in Azure

Tags: azure, rest

I'm new to Azure.  I have an API that uses REST to post items to a SQL server database.  My goal is to deploy it to Azure.

I have tested all day and can successfully deploy every other sort of VS project; Razor based, Blazor based, MVC based.  I know they are all basically interchangable but I created unique ones anyway and they all successfully publish to Azure.

The moment I include any REST functionality both VS and Azure say the deployment was successful, there are no errors, but if you click on the link to the site, there is nothing there.  No error either.  I can't seem to ping the site either.  I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't seem to see it.

Comment: Did you check the Kudu console?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not a problem** that "if you click on the link to the site, there is nothing there."

**Reproduce:**
[image]

**Reason:**

There is nothing to show because you don't write a `index.html` web page in the root directory of your project.

**Access your api:**

You could access your api through your website like this: `https://{yourwebname}.azurewebsites.net/{yourapi}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Doris LV.  This was the deployment equivelant of a missing semicolon.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, @KeyboardBallAndChain. I'm glad to help.